# No Pagination on Child of a Child Woo Commerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My site is running Wordpress with Porto Theme, using Woo Commerce for Products

I have a parent category called United Kingdom
This Parent Category has pagniation for products on pages at the bottom

In the UK parent category, I have counties, Berkshire, London, Sussex etc
These Child Categories have pagination of pages, 1,2,3 etc. Great

I have made children categories underneath these counties. 
No pagination. How and where should I edit, so that I can make this possible?

Thank you.

Please see a Child Category here:
https://www.franchise-uk.co.uk/united-kingdom/franchises-for-sale-east-sussex/

Please see a Child of a Child Category here: note, no pagination;
https://www.franchise-uk.co.uk/united-kingdom/franchises-for-sale-east-sussex/alciston/

FURTHERMORE, the Child of a child, is pulling in every product from the parent category, once 1x has been added. Once ONE has been added, it pulls in every one from the product?!

Please can someone advise? Thank you much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its issue may be in child category have a only 12 post so check it that's reason not showing pagination.So change Blog pages show at most count 9 via backend(setting>Reading) and check.

Comment: Thanks but these aren't posts these are woo commerce products - it's only showing 12, 12 on all categories that's fine that's my selected number per page, but there's more than 12 and the child of child isn't showing page numbers

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved by external dev company.